# Style file not found in the style library and input is not a valid URL or path, when importing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, styles

I have a customized matplotlib style file, called "mystyle.mplstyle".

In the same folder, I have test.py with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('mystyle.mplstyle')
```

That test.py file runs fine.

But if in a second test2.py file in the same folder, I run the following code:

```
import test
```

It would generate the following error messages:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/.../test2.py", line 1, in 
> import test
> File "C:\Users...\test.py", line 3, in 
> plt.style.use('mystyle.mplstyle')
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs...\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\style\core.py", line 130, in use
> raise IOError(
> OSError: 'mystyle.mplstyle' not found in the style library and input is not a valid URL or path; see `style.available` for list of available styles

Why is that? How to fix the import?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I found this question because I had the same problem.
This is how I solved it:

1. Check where your configuration directory is with `matplotlib.get_configdir()`
2. Your file mplstyle.mplstyle should be placed into this directory for matplotlib configuration files. In many cases, this is `~/.config/matplotlib/stylelib`
3. You may need to create the `/stylebib` folder yourself
4. Run the command `plt.style.reload_library()`
5. Check whether your custom style is available by running `plt.style.available`.

More info on [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html)

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue and i got rid of the error by placing my cutom mplstyle file in the same directory where Matplotlib stores its mplstyle files:

`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib`

the custom style can be set in your code using the cutom mplstyle file name without its extension: `plt.style.use('mystyle')`